# VS 2017. Can't access Properties.Settings from another project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

There are three projects in my solution. TFR_cons is the startup project. I am trying to access Properties.Settings from another project MDB_access - have no luck in this at all. In startup project > settings it is set to Public.
But I can get the access from the startup project easily:

[image: access from the same project]
[image: access from another project]

Comment: You would need a reference to the startup project but I assume the startup project references it so you can't have a circular reference. And using the same namespace confuses the issue more. If you need shared settings you can create a project specifically for storing settings.